# serve -s build is showing black screen is i try to change to change context path in react

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a project where I need to deploy my React application as non root URL,
so what I have done is change the homepage property to "homepage": "/app"
and in all routes I have used this syntax

```
<Route exact path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/home`} component={() => (
   <h1> My home </h1>
)} />
```

But when I run `npm run build` and then `serve -s build`, all I see is blank screen with 2 or 3 errors on the console

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
main.e862b16e.chunk.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

I need to deploy this with pm2 as well as with nginx as a non root path.

Comment: You need to post more information about your build tooling. Your configs seem to be incorrect, but we can't help if we can't see them.

Comment: I am using npm serve for building on my local machine but the build is showing blank screen when run serve -s build because i have added homepage property in package.json file to change the base path of my url @NickMcCurdy

Comment: It's still not really clear where the issue is coming from. Can you share your repository?

Comment: okay @NickMcCurdy let me share

Comment: basically i am trying to change the root context of my react application

Comment: normally react app runs on root (i.e localhost:3000)
but what i am trying to do is (localhost:3000/app)

Comment: @NickMcCurdy 
here is repo URL
git clone https://Akif27@bitbucket.org/Akif27/react-app.git

Comment: @NickMcCurdy Are you there ?

Comment: What URL is giving you issues? http://localhost:3000/app works for me.